# How can I remove similar colors of a BitmapData in ActionScript 3? JPG Artifacts removal

Tags: actionscript-3, filter, jpeg, artifacts

I was wondering if there is a filter or something in ActionScript 3 that lets me remove colors that are similar to other colors in a photo?

I have BitmapData of a JPEG image but the JPEG was saved with pretty low quality so there are some pixels that make it look ugly (JPEG artifacts). Without those pictures it would look okay, is there a way of removing them in AS3?

Was thinking something like a ColorMatrixFilter or similar?

Comment: The problem is, when you remove artifacts, you will need some pixels that is put in their place. Else you will have empty gaps in your image and that is also not wanted. There is no real way to remove artifacts. I can give you code to look for colors within a certain range, but that won't let you remove artifacts.

Comment: Not really.. Well I mean, there's no strategy that would be worthwhile. This is why images are optimized using **image optimization software** before they're made use of in applications.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such thing for that. It would be very hard to detect the 'bad zones' and fix them with some surrounding colors. However you could apply a filter (blur or median filter) on your image with a very low setting to improve a bit. Try the [median filter](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000692.php), use a radius of 1; it could improve the image smoothness a bit, while it reduces the photo realism.

Comment: Thanks, though it's critical for me that the image doesn't get any blurry. The pixels must be sharp so to speak, so doesn't sound like an option. It's funny that this filter doesn't exist in AS3 since Adobe are the same guys that do Photoshop. You'd think they would boost the image operations in Flash...